# Docker container random segmentation fault

Tags: python, docker, opencv, containers

I am trying to run an application on a Docker container, but the program is randomly generating segmentation faults. Sometimes the code runs as it is supposed to. Other times, when I interrupt its execution (Ctrl + C) and run it again, it segfaults.

Below is my Dockerfile and the output from gdb. I can see that the problem boils down to cv2.VideoCapture, but I already tried a few fixes (like [locales](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17141)) and it didn't work. On the host machine (i.e., outside the container) the code runs fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-devel

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3-opencv locales gdb python3-dbg ca-certificates python3-dev git wget sudo unzip vim \
        libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev \
        libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-glx0-dev \
        libdbus-1-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev \
        zlib1g-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libfontconfig1-dev \
        cmake ninja-build protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev build-essential wget libssl1.0-dev > /dev/null && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN ln -sv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# create a non-root user
ARG USER_ID=1000
RUN useradd -m --no-log-init --system  --uid ${USER_ID} appuser -g sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER appuser
WORKDIR /home/appuser

ENV PATH="/home/appuser/.local/bin:${PATH}"
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
        python3 get-pip.py --user && \
        rm get-pip.py

# install dependencies
# See https://pytorch.org/ for other options if you use a different version of CUDA
RUN pip install --user tensorboard cython
RUN pip install --user torch torchvision
RUN pip install --user 'git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI'
RUN pip install --user pandas scipy
RUN pip install --user flask flask-cors requests azure-iot-device paho-mqtt
RUN pip install --user PyQt5 imutils QDarkStyle

RUN pip install --user 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/fvcore'
# install detectron2
git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2 detectron2_repo
# the following line are used to checkout a specific version
WORKDIR /home/appuser/detectron2_repo
RUN git checkout 3bdf3ab4a4626985b3581da0a5b9e8c534b56980
WORKDIR /home/appuser/

# set FORCE_CUDA because during `docker build` cuda is not accessible
ENV FORCE_CUDA="1"
# This will by default build detectron2 for all common cuda architectures and take a lot more time,
# because inside `docker build`, there is no way to tell which architecture will be used.
ARG TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="Kepler;Kepler+Tesla;Maxwell;Maxwell+Tegra;Pascal;Volta;Turing"
ENV TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="${TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST}"

RUN pip install --user -e detectron2_repo


#-----------------------------------------------------
VOLUME /jvision

# Copy changed files accordingly
COPY detectron_jvision/core/detectron2 /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/detectron2
COPY demo/ /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/demo
RUN mkdir -p /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/imgs
COPY detectron_jvision/configs/ /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/configs/
COPY detectron_jvision/tools/ /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/tools/
#COPY testeqt.py /home/appuser/detectron2_repo

#RUN sudo cp -R /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/tools /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/detectron2/
#RUN sudo cp -R /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/configs /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/detectron2/

COPY testcases/ jvision/testcases
COPY run.sh /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/demo
COPY run_mask.sh /home/appuser/detectron2_repo
COPY run_mask2.sh /home/appuser/detectron2_repo

RUN /bin/bash -c 'sudo chmod +x /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/demo/run.sh'
RUN /bin/bash -c 'sudo chmod +x /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/run_mask.sh'
RUN /bin/bash -c 'sudo chmod +x /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/run_mask2.sh'
RUN /bin/bash -c 'sudo chmod 777 /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/demo/imgs'
RUN /bin/bash -c 'sudo chmod 777 /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/imgs'
#-----------------------------------------------------

# Update numpy
RUN pip install --user -U numpy

# Set a fixed model cache directory.
ENV FVCORE_CACHE="/tmp"
WORKDIR /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/demo
RUN wget # here I download some weights for my model
RUN sudo unzip -o weights_models.zip
RUN rm weights_models.zip
CMD ["/home/appuser/detectron2_repo/demo/run.sh"]
```

I run it as: `docker run -it -p 5000:5000 --gpus all --name vision --memory='16g' jvision:latest /bin/bash`

Then I try to run my code inside the container, which is when the random segfaults begin.

Here is the gdb output:

```
#0  __strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:948
#1  0x00007f9d25b59bd7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
#2  0x00007f9d25b5b984 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
#3  0x00007f9d25b5c1fa in lt_dlopenadvise () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
#4  0x00007f9d25b5c2c0 in lt_dlopenext () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
#5  0x00007f9d33dd5aa7 in gp_abilities_list_load_dir () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgphoto2.so.6
#6  0x00007f9d33dd5e19 in gp_abilities_list_load () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgphoto2.so.6
#7  0x00007f9d33dd8334 in gp_camera_autodetect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgphoto2.so.6
#8  0x00007f9d39eecdd5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
#9  0x00007f9d39ef2d65 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
#10 0x00007f9d39ef2e98 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
#11 0x00007f9d39ed43ea in cv::VideoCapture::open(cv::String const&, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
#12 0x00007f9d39ed45fe in cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(cv::String const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
#13 0x00007f9d3df071f0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#14 0x000000000050a635 in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (kwargs=<optimized out>, nargs=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, func_obj=<built-in function VideoCapture>) at ../Objects/methodobject.c:231
#15 _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords (kwnames=<optimized out>, nargs=<optimized out>, stack=<optimized out>, func=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/methodobject.c:294
#16 call_function.lto_priv () at ../Python/ceval.c:4851
#17 0x000000000050bfb4 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at ../Python/ceval.c:3335
#18 0x0000000000507d64 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0, f=Frame 0x7f9c72e281f8, for file /home/appuser/detectron2_repo/demo/multicam_new.py, line 64, in load_network_stream_thread ())
    at ../Python/ceval.c:754
#19 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName.lto_priv.1820 () at ../Python/ceval.c:4166
#20 0x0000000000588d41 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (closure=<optimized out>, kwdefs=<optimized out>, defcount=0, defs=0x0, kwcount=0, kws=0x7f9d3f81d060, argcount=<optimized out>, args=0x7f9d3f81d060, 
    locals=0x0, globals=<optimized out>, _co=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4187
#21 function_call.lto_priv () at ../Objects/funcobject.c:604
#22 0x000000000059fc4e in PyObject_Call () at ../Objects/abstract.c:2261
#23 0x000000000050d356 in do_call_core (kwdict={}, callargs=(), func=<function at remote 0x7f9c61cddb70>) at ../Python/ceval.c:5120
#24 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at ../Python/ceval.c:3404
#25 0x0000000000509758 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0, 
    f=Frame 0x7f9c72e2b238, for file /usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py, line 864, in run (self=<Thread(_target=<function at remote 0x7f9c61cddb70>, _name='Thread-1', _args=(), _kwargs={}, _daemonic=True, _ident=140309919069952, _tstate_lock=<_thread.lock at remote 0x7f9c72eada58>, _started=<Event(_cond=<Condition(_lock=<_thread.lock at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, acquire=<built-in method acquire of _thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, release=<built-in method release of _thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, _waiters=<collections.deque at remote 0x7f9c7303fa08>) at remote 0x7f9cefecf828>, _flag=True) at remote 0x7f9d3e333fd0>, _is_stopped=False, _initialized=True, _stderr=<_io.TextIOWrapper at remote 0x7f9d3f804708>) at remote 0x7f9c731140b8>)) at ../Python/ceval.c:754
#26 _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=140309919085112, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4933
#27 fast_function.lto_priv () at ../Python/ceval.c:4968
#28 0x000000000050a48d in call_function.lto_priv () at ../Python/ceval.c:4872
#29 0x000000000050bfb4 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at ../Python/ceval.c:3335
#30 0x0000000000509758 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0, 
    f=Frame 0x7f9c3c000b38, for file /usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py, line 916, in _bootstrap_inner (self=<Thread(_target=<function at remote 0x7f9c61cddb70>, _name='Thread-1', _args=(), _kwargs={}, _daemonic=True, _ident=140309919069952, _tstate_lock=<_thread.lock at remote 0x7f9c72eada58>, _started=<Event(_cond=<Condition(_lock=<_thread.lock at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, acquire=<built-in method acquire of _thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, release=<built-in method release of _thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, _waiters=<collections.deque at remote 0x7f9c7303fa08>) at remote 0x7f9cefecf828>, _flag=True) at remote 0x7f9d3e333fd0>, _is_stopped=False, _initialized=True, _stderr=<_io.TextIOWrapper at remote 0x7f9d3f804708>) at remote 0x7f9c731140b8>)) at ../Python/ceval.c:754
#31 _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=140308998261560, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4933
#32 fast_function.lto_priv () at ../Python/ceval.c:4968
#33 0x000000000050a48d in call_function.lto_priv () at ../Python/ceval.c:4872
#34 0x000000000050bfb4 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () at ../Python/ceval.c:3335
#35 0x0000000000508e55 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0, 
    f=Frame 0x7f9c72e4d7e8, for file /usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py, line 884, in _bootstrap (self=<Thread(_target=<function at remote 0x7f9c61cddb70>, _name='Thread-1', _args=(), _kwargs={}, _daemonic=True, _ident=140309919069952, _tstate_lock=<_thread.lock at remote 0x7f9c72eada58>, _started=<Event(_cond=<Condition(_lock=<_thread.lock at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, acquire=<built-in method acquire of _thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, release=<built-in method release of _thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9c79db0418>, _waiters=<collections.deque at remote 0x7f9c7303fa08>) at remote 0x7f9cefecf828>, _flag=True) at remote 0x7f9d3e333fd0>, _is_stopped=False, _initialized=True, _stderr=<_io.TextIOWrapper at remote 0x7f9d3f804708>) at remote 0x7f9c731140b8>)) at ../Python/ceval.c:754
#36 _PyFunction_FastCall (globals=<optimized out>, nargs=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4933
#37 _PyFunction_FastCallDict () at ../Python/ceval.c:5035
#38 0x0000000000594931 in _PyObject_FastCallDict (kwargs=0x0, nargs=1, args=0x7f9c72e26df0, func=<function at remote 0x7f9d3e24e510>) at ../Objects/abstract.c:2310
#39 _PyObject_Call_Prepend (kwargs=0x0, args=<optimized out>, obj=<optimized out>, func=<function at remote 0x7f9d3e24e510>) at ../Objects/abstract.c:2373
#40 method_call.lto_priv () at ../Objects/classobject.c:314
#41 0x000000000059fc4e in PyObject_Call () at ../Objects/abstract.c:2261
#42 0x00000000005e11c2 in t_bootstrap () at ../Modules/_threadmodule.c:1000
#43 0x00000000006319a4 in pythread_wrapper (arg=<optimized out>) at ../Python/thread_pthread.h:205
#44 0x00007f9d3f04f6db in start_thread (arg=0x7f9c72e27700) at pthread_create.c:463
#45 0x00007f9d3f38888f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

Line 64 of multicam_new.py (#18) is a cv2.VideoCapture command. I use threads to read from multiple camera streams and process their frames accordingly.

Comment: It looks like OpenCV is trying to use libgphoto2 as its camera backend, and things related to it are breaking. Either make sure it's properly installed, or maybe hack the code opening the OpenCV VideoCapture to explicitly not use Gphoto; see https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d for a list.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help. I tried using GSTREAMER and FFMPEG, but the segfault persisted. What did fix the problem, however, was the headless version of OpenCV (```pip install opencv-python-headless```). I installed it and everything worked as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who might come across this problem, use the *headless* version of opencv `pip install opencv-python-headless`

This is what finally fixed the random segmentation fault problem.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: It's been a while since I dealt with this problem. Are you also trying to use OpenCV inside your container? Can you share some more details?

Comment: yep, was using open cv inside my container. This issue does not repro for me anymore. But I do have opencv-python in my container successfully without any segmentation faults now.